# movement verbs in Konjunktiv II (perfekt)

Tags: subjunctive, auxiliary-verb

I knew how I can make Konjunktiv II (perfekt). I use this formula (hätten+infinitiv+modal verb im infinitiv):
for example:

> Ich hätte nicht so viel fernsehen dürfen.

but if verb is movement type, how should I make it? Should I use *wären* instead of *hätten*?
which one is correct?

> Ich wäre mehr gehen sollen.

> Ich hätte mehr gehen sollen.

Comment: _"Should I use _wären_ instead of _hätten_?"_ No. What actually makes you think so? Please clarify that in your question.

Comment: if there is a movement verb in a sentence, to make a Konjunktiv II (perfekt), should I use <wären> or <hätten>?

Comment: The movement verb doesn't matter in that case, the primary relation is _sollen_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These sentences contain the perfect of modal verbs. Modal verbs form their perfect with *haben*. The infinitive governed by the modal verb (marked as V<sub>inf</sub> below) does not enter into the choice of perfect auxiliary.

> Ich **habe** … V<sub>inf</sub> **dürfen**.

You formed the subjunctive of the past correctly by putting the auxiliary into *Konjunktiv II*.

> Ich **hätte** … V<sub>inf</sub> **dürfen**.

*Wäre* appears when the modal verb is removed if V<sub>inf</sub> forms the perfect with *sein*.

> Ich **wäre** **gegangen**.

But:

> Ich **hätte** **ferngesehen**.

Comment: so, [Ich hätte mehr gehen sollen.] is in a correct form. and using wäre in this sentence is not acceptable?

Comment: @Toobatf Yes on both counts.